# Space before theorems using ntheorem and add-ons using mdframed

Tags: mdframed, ntheorem

I've developed the attached framework for my mathematical developments using several inputs. Anyway, I have faced two inconveniences:

1. I would like to add space before each theorem.
2. I would like also to have a single environment for the information paragraphs. I've developed two different because {info} does not support page breaks and {mdframed}[style=infoframe] when used in a single page (short text) is unable to print the (i) symbol at the beginning of the paragraph

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
%
\usepackage[skip=1\baselineskip, indent=0pt]{parskip}
%
\usepackage{mathtools}
%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
%
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
%
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage{longtable}
%

\usepackage[thmmarks,framed,amsmath,thref]{ntheorem}%

\theoremseparator{:}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newframedtheorem{importantTheorem}[theorem]{Theorem}
%
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newframedtheorem{importantProp}[prop]{Proposition}
%
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newframedtheorem{importantdefn}[defn]{Definition}
\newtheorem{fact}{Fact}[chapter]
%
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{axioms}{Axioms}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}

\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
% ---------------------------------------------- Remove numbering from theorem-style items
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\newframedtheorem{remark}{Remark}
%
\theoremsymbol{$\blacksquare$}
%
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
%----------------------------------------------------------- Additional frames style
%   Principal MPD frame type
\mdfdefinestyle{mpdframe}{
    frametitlebackgroundcolor   =black!15,
    frametitlerule          =true,
        roundcorner     =10pt,
        middlelinewidth     =1pt,
        innermargin     =0.5cm,
        outermargin     =0.5cm,
        innerleftmargin     =0.5cm,
        innerrightmargin        =0.5cm,
        innertopmargin      =\topskip,
        innerbottommargin   =\topskip,
            }

\mdfdefinestyle{note}{%
        style=mpdframe,
       frametitle={Remark},
   }
\newmdenv[style=note]{note}
%----------------------------------------------------------    Style = Note
\mdfdefinestyle{info}{%
    topline=false, bottomline=false,
    leftline=false, rightline=false,
    nobreak,
    singleextra={%
        \fill[black](P-|O)circle[radius=0.5em];
%       \node at(P-|O){\color{white}\scriptsize\bf i};
        \node at(P-|O){\color{white}\scriptsize\bf i};
        \draw[very thick](P-|O)++(0,-0.8em)--(O);%--(O-|P);
    }
}
\newmdenv[style=info]{info}
%-------------------------------------------------------------- Style = info
\mdfdefinestyle{question}{
    innertopmargin=1.2\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=0.8\baselineskip,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    nobreak,
    singleextra={%
        \draw(P-|O)node[xshift=1em,anchor=west,fill=white,draw,rounded corners=5pt]{%
        Question \theQuestion\questionTitle};
    },
}

\newcounter{Question} % Stores the current question number that gets iterated with each new question

% -------------------------------------------------------------- Style = Question
% Define a custom environment for numbered questions
\newenvironment{question}[1][\unskip]{
    \bigskip
    \stepcounter{Question}
    \newcommand{\questionTitle}{~#1}
    \begin{mdframed}[style=question]
}{
    \end{mdframed}
    \medskip
}
%\newmdenv[style=question]{question}
\global\mdfdefinestyle{infoframe}{%
linecolor=black,linewidth=1.25pt,%
topline=false, bottomline=false, rightline=false,%
leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=1cm,
    firstextra={%
        \fill[black](P-|O)circle[radius=0.5em];
%       \node at(P-|O){\color{white}\scriptsize\bf i};
        \node at(P-|O){\color{white}\scriptsize\bf i};
        \draw[very thick](P-|O)++(0,-0.8em)--(O);%--(O-|P);
    }
}
%-----------------------------------------------------Surrounds proofs with leftbar
\surroundwithmdframed[
  topline=false,
  rightline=false,
  bottomline=false,
  leftmargin=\parindent,
  skipabove=\medskipamount,
  skipbelow=\medskipamount
]{proof}

%----------------------------------------------------------  Document


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    The fundamental theorem of calculus is a theorem that links the concept of differentiating a function (calculating its slopes, or rate of change at each time) with the concept of integrating a function (calculating the area under its graph, or the cumulative effect of small contributions). The two operations are inverses of each other apart from a constant value which depends on where one starts to compute area.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Suppose that m is evenly divisible by n. (This is where you assume that statement A is true.) This means that m = kn for some integer k. Suppose that m + 1 was also divisible by n. (This is where you assume that statement B is false. Now use this information!) The fact that m + 1 is evenly divisible by n means that m + 1 = jn for some integer j. Since we have both m = kn and m + 1 = jn, this implies that...
\end{proof}
\begin{importantTheorem}
    The fundamental theorem of calculus is a theorem that links the concept of differentiating a function (calculating its slopes, or rate of change at each time) with the concept of integrating a function (calculating the area under its graph, or the cumulative effect of small contributions). The two operations are inverses of each other apart from a constant value which depends on where one starts to compute area.
\end{importantTheorem}
\begin{proof}
    Suppose that m is evenly divisible by n. (This is where you assume that statement A is true.) This means that m = kn for some integer k. Suppose that m + 1 was also divisible by n. (This is where you assume that statement B is false. Now use this information!) The fact that m + 1 is evenly divisible by n means that m + 1 = jn for some integer j. Since we have both m = kn and m + 1 = jn, this implies that...
\end{proof}
\begin{prop}
   The fundamental theorem of calculus is a theorem that links the concept of differentiating a function (calculating its slopes, or rate of change at each time) with the concept of integrating a function (calculating the area under its graph, or the cumulative effect of small contributions). The two operations are inverses of each other apart from a constant value which depends on where one starts to compute area.
\end{prop}
\begin{importantProp}
    The fundamental theorem of calculus is a theorem that links the concept of differentiating a function (calculating its slopes, or rate of change at each time) with the concept of integrating a function (calculating the area under its graph, or the cumulative effect of small contributions). The two operations are inverses of each other apart from a constant value which depends on where one starts to compute area.
\end{importantProp}
\begin{remark}
    Nota
\end{remark}
\begin{theorem}
    The fundamental theorem of calculus is a theorem that links the concept of differentiating a function (calculating its slopes, or rate of change at each time) with the concept of integrating a function (calculating the area under its graph, or the cumulative effect of small contributions). The two operations are inverses of each other apart from a constant value which depends on where one starts to compute area.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Suppose that m is evenly divisible by n. (This is where you assume that statement A is true.) This means that m = kn for some integer k. Suppose that m + 1 was also divisible by n. (This is where you assume that statement B is false. Now use this information!) The fact that m + 1 is evenly divisible by n means that m + 1 = jn for some integer j. Since we have both m = kn and m + 1 = jn, this implies that...  
\end{proof}
\begin{corollary}
    Facts supported by the corollary
\end{corollary}

\vspace{12pt}
\begin{info}
    Suppose that m is evenly divisible by n. (This is where you assume that statement A is true.) This means that m = kn for some integer k. Suppose that m + 1 was also divisible by n. (This is where you assume that statement B is false. Now use this information!) The fact that m + 1 is evenly divisible by n means that m + 1 = jn for some integer j. Since we have both m = kn and m + 1 = jn, this implies that...  
\end{info}

%\vspace{12pt}
\begin{mdframed}[style=infoframe]
    \lipsum
\end{mdframed}
\vspace{20pt}
\begin{mdframed}[style=infoframe]
 Suppose that m is evenly divisible by n. (This is where you assume that statement A is true.) This means that m = kn for some integer k. Suppose that m + 1 was also divisible by n. (This is where you assume that statement B is false. Now use this information!) The fact that m + 1 is evenly divisible by n means that m + 1 = jn for some integer j. Since we have both m = kn and m + 1 = jn, this implies that... 
 \end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```